# dishwasher wiring

Tags: dishwasher, wire

so  the power cable I need to hook up to dishwasher has one white one tanish color and then the ground so do I go white whit black to the tanish and then green to ground the bare copper one?

Comment: What country are you in?  And what do the dishwasher's instructions say to do (or what's the model number if you don't have the instructions?)

Comment: Can you post photos of the power cable?

Comment: You are probably correct **BUT**  you need to know for sure.  **You need to use a tester to determine which wire is hot**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with the process use a voltage meter and determine which conductor is hot.  Then permanently mark it with a fat black magic marker.

Comment: Black is appropriate for the US, but not necessarily other countries, and OP didn't indicate. Still, +1 on principle.

Answer (score 0):

should have 1 black, 1 white, and 1 green or bare copper, black is normally the hot leg, white is neutral and green wire is ground, always use a volt meter and check black to ground and white to ground to see which is the hot leg.

Comment: This is valid for the US (North America in general), but wire color standards vary around the world and OP didn't indicate what country she's in.